# [Switchboard]: undef rebar_utils:wordsize, [],[] when compiling lager, gproc, jsx, poolboy

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3

I'm trying to get [switchboard](https://github.com/thusfresh/switchboard) compiled on a Debian linux. I'm asking here since their supported install is just Virtualbox.

I'm getting a bunch of what I expect are Rebar version related issues, but I'm pretty new so that could be very wrong.

Here's the backtrace from running `make`

```
DEP    lager
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rebar_utils,wordsize,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,670}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,228}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,229}]},{erl_eval,expr_list,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,878}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,422}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]},{init,start_it,1,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
DEP    gproc
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rebar_utils,wordsize,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,670}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,228}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,229}]},{erl_eval,expr_list,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,878}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,422}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]},{init,start_it,1,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
DEP    cowboy
DEP    jsx
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rebar_utils,wordsize,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,670}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,228}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,229}]},{erl_eval,expr_list,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,878}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,422}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]},{init,start_it,1,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
DEP    poolboy
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rebar_utils,wordsize,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,670}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,228}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,229}]},{erl_eval,expr_list,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,878}]},{erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,422}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]},{init,start_it,1,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/switchboard/deps/lager'
make[1]: *** No targets.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/switchboard/deps/lager
```

I have installed rebar using `mix local.rebar` (I'm coming from Elixir land). I've tried with both `rebar` and `rebar3`.

Anyone have any ideas? The only google result I have found is [this poor fellow](https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd/issues/704) who has the same issue, seemingly without resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had apparently gotten my repo in a bad state.

I think I didn't have all the necessary libraries when I originally ran `make`.

I deleted my local checkout and re-cloned the repo and was able to compile it.